# Frontend in WP , backend in Laravel. Some level of integration needed

Tags: php, single-sign-on, third-party-applications

I plan to use WP for my platform's frontend and Laravel 5 for my backend work.

I will not use WP functionality for my core business. But i will need to have a forum in WP and some other lightweight services, alongside the main site.

1) This means that i will need to have some kind of single sign on between Laravel and WP. How would i do it? I prefer user profiles to be in Laravel as i will need much more info and functionality from what WP profiles.

2) Look and feel. I have found and worked with soem great WP templates like enfold and X from themeforest. I want to use html metronic  template for my backend. are there any best practices when i will try to make them look the same? Is there any top level template that has aWP and HTML version?

3) Using WP function in Laravel and vice versa. Any opinions / experience in this?

Additional Info / reasoning behind my task:

My front end will not be simple and i want to have a simple blog platform / subscriptions /forum. Why to build it from scratch?

My backend on the other hand will be a simple but yet full custom solution that it would be a pain to do in WP.

Comment: attempting this makes no sense to me. the amount of work involved to somehow use the API with an entirely different back end seems impossibly complicated. you may as well write the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: @Rarst gave a great answer to what essentially amounts to the same question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175235/17879).

Comment: the main reason for my request is: My front end will not be simple and i wan tto have a simple blog platform / subscriptions /forum. Why to build it from scratch?

My backend on the other hand will be a simple but yet full custom solution that it would be a pain to do in WP.

Comment: @e4rthdog did you manage to finish your project? I am starting doing the same thing... front end using wp capabilities, stil using the backend of wordpress.. but for user login, user payment validation and subscription validation through my laravel api... would you mind share your current thoughts on that? Thanks